How to find basis of Hamiltonian Matrices?
Background
Basis of a Hamiltonian means the set of vectors over which the function is defined, so for a wave function $|\psi\rangle$ basis is a set of vectors  $\{ | \phi_i \rangle \}$  that span the Hilbert space. Any state  $|\psi\rangle$  can be written as a linear combination of these basis vectors:
$$
|\psi\rangle = \sum_i c_i | \phi_i \rangle
$$
The hamiltonian in TB the equation is $$
H = -t \sum_{\langle i,j \rangle} \left( c_i^\dagger c_j + c_j^\dagger c_i \right) + \sum_i \epsilon_i c_i^\dagger c_i
$$
where the $c_i$ and $c_j$ are the basis.
Question
When dealing with TB models of say 1d chain or 2d lattice we get hamiltonian matrices of the form $$ H = \begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon & t & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
t & \epsilon & t & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & t & \epsilon & t & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & t & \epsilon
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is for a $N$-atom 1d chain. where $t$ is the hopping parameter and $\epsilon$ is the on site energy. My doubt is how to know the basis of such matrices and how do these basis relate to the eigenvalues?

What do you mean by "bases of these matrices"? Do you mean what is  the basis of a vector space on which this matrix defines a linear opertor?

I don't think this is a problem of statistical mechanics.

Have you diagonalized the 2x2 and 3x3 cases?

The basis of the Hamiltonian you provide is the basis of the eigenmodes on each lattice site. Usually, we don't care about what this mode exactly is and just associate it with some abstract vector $|j\rangle$. The main diagonal elements of the matrix tell you how each mode interacts with itself whereas the off-diagonal elements tell you the interaction, ie. couplings, of modes on different sites. In your case, we have nearest neighbor hopping where $t$ determines the coupling/hopping strength.
You can see this by expressing the Hamiltonian as sum of projection operators on all possible combinations of position eigenmodes of the system. If you have $N$ sites, each supporting a single mode, you will obtain $N^2$ projection operators $\hat{P}_{jk} = | j \rangle \!\langle k|$ with amplitudes given by the $\hat{H}_{jk}$ element of your Hamiltonian.
When you diagonalize your Hamiltonian, you obtain another basis given by the eigen- or supermodes $|\psi_j \rangle$ of the entire lattice - which is simply linear combinations of the position basis modes of the lattice. Since they are eigenmodes of $\hat{H}$, they obey the eigenvalue equation $\hat{H} |\psi_j \rangle = \lambda_j |\psi_j \rangle$. If you express $\hat{H}$ in the basis $\lbrace|\psi_j \rangle \rbrace$, it will be diagonal with the elements $\hat{H}_{jj} = \lambda_j$.
I recommend reading about coupled mode theory - the equivalent approach often employed in the context of waveguiding structures such as multicore fibers or lattices of waveguides. These systems obey the same dynamics but the meaning of the different terms is much more descriptive. The main diagonal elements $\epsilon$ will correspond to the propagation constant $\beta_j$ or, equivalently, to the effective refractive index $n_{\text{eff},j}$ of the eigenmode of the waveguide at position $j$. The off-diagonal elements $t$ will tell you how much of the energy in mode $|j\rangle$ of waveguide $j$ couples into another mode $|k\rangle$ of waveguide $k$.
